# Group by multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Tables:

```
a: org1, class, class_id
b: org2, class, class_id
```

I did a `left outer join b on a.class_id = b.class_id`

Results:

```
  org1  |  org 2  | class
--------+---------+------------------
ENGLISH | ENGLISH | English 101
ENGLISH | ENGLISH | English 220
ENGLISH | COMM    | Communication 360
ENGLISH | HISTORY | History 362
HISTORY | ENGLISH | English 366
```

I want to know if it's possible to achieve the following grouping via SQL or programmatically using the results data set from above?

```
ORG: ENGLISH
     -----------------
     English 101       
     English 220         
     Communication 360
     History 362
     English 366
     -----------------
ORG: HISTORY
     -----------------
     English 366
     History 362
     -----------------
     COMM
     -----------------
     Communication 360
```

- Any class with an ENGLISH org1 or org2 should show under ENGLISH org.
- Any class with a HISTORY org1 or org2 should show under HISTORY org.
- Any class with a COMM org1 or org2 should show under COMM org.
- If they have another org (Communication 360 is both ENGLISH/COMM), it should show under *both* ENGLISH org and COMM org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT t.org, t.class
FROM
(
    SELECT org1 AS org, class
    FROM a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT org2 AS org, class
    FROM b
) t
ORDER BY t.org, t.class
```

EDIT: (by gordon)

You don't need the subquery:

```
    SELECT org1 AS org, class
    FROM a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT org2 AS org, class
    FROM b
    ORDER BY org, class;
```

The `ORDER BY` applies to the *result* of the `union all`.

Comment: You don't need the subquery.